# Prove $\left(1 + 1/\sqrt{n}\right)^n > \sqrt{n}$ for all natural $n$

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

$$\left(1 + 1/\sqrt{n}\right)^n > \sqrt{n}$$

I'm trying to use Bernoulli's inequality

So $\left(1 + 1/\sqrt{n}\right)^n \ge 1 + n/\sqrt{n}$, but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Could I say that $1 + n/\sqrt{n} > \sqrt{n}$ for all natural numbers so the above statement holds true?

Comment: Yes you could.${}$

Comment: $\frac{n}{\sqrt n} \times \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n} = \sqrt n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
1 + \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}
  = 1 + \sqrt{n} > \sqrt{n}
$$