# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{n} < (1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2$ for all n in the naturals.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, radicals

I need to prove that $\sqrt[n]{n} < (1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2$ for all n in the naturals.
I started by using Bernoulli's inequality: 
$(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}) < (1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2$
I can say that:
$(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}) = (1+\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n})$
I can also subtract the one and divide by 2 on the left side without changing the inequality (because it makes it even smaller): $(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}) < (1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2$
But now I am stuck...

Comment: I think it must be $$n\geq 1$$

Comment: Have you tried using and induction argument?

Comment: For us, we don't include 0 in the naturals, so yes it is ≥1

Comment: I cannot follow your argumentation.

Comment: Now that you said that, I tried proving it by induction, but I don't really know where to go from for proving the n+1 inequality.

Comment: @MartinR possible duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505239/505767).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+{1\over\sqrt n}\right)^{2n}
&=\left(1+{2\over\sqrt n}+{1\over n}\right)^n\\
&\gt\left(1+{2\over\sqrt n} \right)^n\\
&\ge1+{n\choose1}{2\over\sqrt n}+{n\choose2}\left(2\over\sqrt n\right)^2\\
&\gt1+0+2(n-1)\\
&=2n-1\\
&\ge n
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah, this is not much different from Zhanxiong's answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Inequality Requested**
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{2n}
&\ge\left(1+\sqrt{n}\right)^2\tag1\\
&\ge n\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$(2)$: $1+\sqrt{n}\ge\sqrt{n}$

---

**Slightly Stronger Inequality**
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\sqrt{\frac2n}\right)^n
&\ge1+n\sqrt{\frac2n}+\frac{n(n-1)}2\frac2n\tag3\\
&\ge n\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: Binomial Theorem
$(4)$: $n+\sqrt{2n}\ge n$

Comment: Bernoulli works!

Answer (score 3):

Beware: overkill incoming. We may use the AM-GM inequality for producing tight bounds for $\sqrt[n]{n}$.
 In particular, by noticing that
$$ n = 1\cdot \frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n}{n-1} $$
we have
$$ \sqrt[n]{n}=\text{GM}\left(1,1+1,1+\frac{1}{2},\ldots,1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)<\text{AM}\left(1,1+1,1+\frac{1}{2},\ldots,1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right) $$
and 
$$ \sqrt[n]{n} < 1+ \frac{H_{n-1}}{n},\qquad \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2=1+\frac{2\sqrt{n}+1}{n}, $$
so it is enough to show that $H_{n-1}\leq 2\sqrt{n}+1$, at least from some point on.
 On the other hand the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ensures
$$ H_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}1\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2}} < \sqrt{n\zeta(2)} $$
and we are done.

Comment: Nice. It might be also interesting to use that $$H_{n-1}\le \ln(n)+1$$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534053/) And that $$2\sqrt x-\ln(x)$$ is positive for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as $n\le (1+1/\sqrt n)^{2n}.$ Expanding  using the binomial formula, we want

$$n\le \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}1^{2n-k}(1/\sqrt n)^k.$$

Conisder the $k=2$ term in the sum.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to prove 
$$ n < \left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{2n}.$$

By the binomial identity, the right hand side is at least
\begin{align*}
& 1 + \binom{2n}{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \binom{2n}{2}\frac{1}{n} \\
= & 1 + 2\sqrt{n} + 2n - 1 \\
= & 2n + 2\sqrt{n} \\
> & n.
\end{align*}

Comment: The middle term is superfluous.

Comment: @amsmath True, just want to demonstrate how to expand to the quadratic term.

Comment: Oh wow! I hadn't thought about the first step you did. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Zhanxiong this solution is wrong. If $n=1$, then it's not the case that "the right hand side is greater than ...". It is equal to it.

Comment: @mathworker21 Will make it more rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+x)^n \ge (n^2/4) x^2 $, $n \ge 1$, $x \ge 0$.

Proof:

$(1+x)^n=$

$1+nx + (n(n-1)/2!)x^2+...\gt (n(n-1)/2)x^2 \ge (n^2/4)x^2,$

since we have

$(n)((n-1)/2) \ge n( n/4)$,  for $n\ge 2.$

Let $x=2/√n$, in

$(1+x)^n > (n^2/4)x^2$;

$1+2/√n \gt \sqrt[n]{n}$, $n \ge 1$.

Finally

$(1+2/√n)^2 >(1+2/√n) \gt \sqrt[n]{n}$, $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Well for natural (positive) $n$ then  $\sqrt[n]{n} \le (1+ \frac 1{\sqrt n})^2 \iff$

$n \le (1 + \frac 1{\sqrt n})^{2n}$

So $(1+\frac 1{\sqrt n})^{2n} \ge 1 + \frac {2n}{\sqrt n}$ and dang... that's not enough.

But lets go one more term.

Remember the reason $(1 + b)^n \ge 1+ nb$ is becase $(1 + b)^n = 1 + nb + C_2b^2 + C_3b^3 + ..... + b^n$ and $C_kb^k \ge 0$.  (Note if $b$ is large and $n>0$, in particular if $b \ge 1$, this is $(1+b)^n \ge 1 + nb$ is a *very* large discrepancy in the inequality).

So $(1+\frac 1{\sqrt n})^{2n} \ge 1 + \frac {2n}{\sqrt n} + {2n \choose 2}\frac 1{n}$.

So ${2n \choose 2} = \frac {2n(2n-1)}2 = n(2n-1)$ so

$(1 + \frac 1{\sqrt n})^{2n} \ge 1 +\frac{2n}{\sqrt n} + n(2n-1)\frac 1n =$

$1 + 2\sqrt n + 2n- 1 = 2(\sqrt n + n) > n$.

.... which if we did that correctly is not even close.